# Developing an Abstract Data Type to convert infix expressions into postfix expressions

Tags: java, arraylist, queue, adt

I need help to decide using between **queue** ADT and **stack** ADT as storage for the infix (input) values.

Also, I need to think about using either **ArrayList** or **LinkedList** to implement one of the above ADTs.

I was thinking to use the queue ADT as storage and then using ArrayList to implement it. The reason for this is because the queue follows the FIFO fashion and ArrayList can be useful in accessing the values much faster than LinkedList.

Could anyone give me professional advice?